# cors issue with nginx, aws and cloudflare

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, cors, cloudflare

I have my site hosted in amazon aws. My apps frontend is built with angular and backend is built with nodejs express framework. the domain is managed using Cloudflare with free SSL certificate from Cloudflare. Server is configured using nginx.

Everything was fine but suddenly my server is returning 403 response. As a result, my APIs stopped working.

**My ngnixn server code:**

```
server {
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.shajao.com;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
        underscores_in_headers on;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass http://shajao_server;

    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    client_body_buffer_size    500M;
    client_max_body_size 500M;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        }

}
```

**My express server cors setup:**

```
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Accept');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

My website url: [www.shajao.com](https://shajao.com/frames)

Comment: can you attach nodejs error code here ?

Comment: I didn't see any error... I added my site url.. U can see cors issue in the console and in network you will see my api is returning 403.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something happened with cloudflare that was creating the cors issue. Removed my domain from cloudflare and managed my dns from godaddy and everything started working without any changes. Not sure what happened from cloudflare side. Would be better if anyone can answer that